# An app Api Services not working With Mobile Data but same working with WiFI in iOS13

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.3, ios13.1.2

Operation System : iOS 13 
Network Library: Alamofire
XCode Version: 10.3

I noticed one thing that Same App is not showing in setting.

Comment: check your device firewall block your call or not

Comment: whats the error shows

Comment: I got the issue It was with alamofire rechability . managed with Rechability class.

Comment: congrtz , please update the answer it will useful for other persons